# Model size on disk way bigger than in memory

Tags: r, r-caret

I created bagged tree model `method = "treebag"`using the caret package in R and the resulting model size is 12 Mb when viewing in R-Studio. But when I save to disk for later use with `save()` the size *on disk* increases to 151 Mb! Using different compression schemes brings the size down a bit but all are still way larger than in memory. Anyone successfully dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The likely reason is that the enclosing environment associated with objects is not considered in the results of object.size(), but is written to disk when saved. Use the pryr::object_size() function to see the object size with environment included. More explanation can be found at: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#object-size

```
> object.size(m1)
16200200 bytes
> pryr::object_size(m1)
215 MB
> save(m1, file="m1.rda")
> file.info("m1.rda")$size
[1] 219475772
```

There also has been some discussion of this issue in another question: [object.size() reports smaller size than .Rdata file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836747/object-size-reports-smaller-size-than-rdata-file)

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about the `train` object?

The `bagging` function isn't very optimized and a lot of redundant objects are saved in the forest (e.g. each `terms` object for every `rpart` model).

See the `trim` option of `trainControl`. If you only want to make predictions on that object, this will get rid of a lot of extra stuff carried over by the model object. In some cases, the `call` object can contain a complete copy of the data.

`trim` isn't implemented for every model but is it for this one.

Comment: Yes, the train object. And yes I used `trim`. But I don't think this is getting to the point. _Why the huge increase when saved to disk?_ I don't think the `trainControl` parameters should affect that.

Comment: PS... I also used `returnData = F`