# Saving a single object within a function in R: RData file size is very large

Tags: r, save, environment, glm, rdata

I am trying to save trimmed-down GLM objects in R (i.e. with all the "non-essential" characteristics set to NULL e.g. residuals, prior.weights, qr$qr).

As an example, looking at the smallest object that I need to do this with:

```
print(object.size(glmObject))
168992 bytes
save(glmObject, "FileName.RData")
```

Assigning this object in the global environment and saving leads to an RData file of about 6KB.

However, I effectively need to create and save the glm object within a function, which is in itself within a function. So the code looks something like:

```
subFn <- function(DT, otherArg, ...){
                 glmObject <- glm(...)
                 save(glmObject,"FileName.RData")
}

mainFn <- function(DT, ...){ 
             subFn(DT, otherArg, ...)
}

mainFn(DT, ...)
```

Which leads to much, much larger RData files of about 20 MB, despite the object itself being the same size.

So I understand this to be an environment issue, but I'm struggling to pinpoint exactly how and why it's happening. The resulting file size seems to vary quite a lot. I have tried using saveRDS, and equally I have tried assigning the glmObject via <<- to make it global, but nothing seems to help.

My understanding of environments in R clearly isn't very good, and would really appreciate if anyone could suggest a way around this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you flesh out your example, including fake data so that your issue is reproducible?

Comment: Yes, and also could you give the output of `object.size` from within the function?

Comment: See the solution proposed here (with code correction in the comments) for plots. It should also work for this case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192298/small-ggplot-object-1-mb-turns-into-7-gigabyte-rdata-object-when-saved/57315001#57315001

Answer (score 8):

Formulas have an environment attached.  If that's the global environment or a package environment, it's not saved, but if it's not one that can be reconstructed, it will be saved.

`glm` results typically contain formulas, so they can contain the environment attached to that formula.

You don't need `glm` to demonstrate this.  Just try this:

```
formula1 <- y ~ x
save(formula1, file = "formula1.Rdata")

f <- function() {
   z <- rnorm(1000000)
   formula2 <- y ~ x
   save(formula2, file = "formula2.Rdata")
}
f()
```

When I run the code above, `formula1.Rdata` ends up at 114 bytes, while `formula2.Rdata` ends up at 7.7 MB.  This is because the latter captures the environment it was created in, and that contains the big vector `z`.

To avoid this, clean up the environment where you created a formula before saving the formula.  Don't delete things that the formula refers to (because `glm` may need those), but do delete irrelevant things (like `z` in my example).  See:

```
g <- function() {
   z <- rnorm(1000000)
   formula3 <- y ~ x
   rm(z)
   save(formula3, file = "formula3.Rdata")
}
g()
```

This gives `formula3.Rdata` of 144 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Do you find that you have the same problem when you name the arguments in your call to `save`?

I used:

```
subFn <- function(y, x){
             glmObject <- glm(y ~ x, family = "binomial")
             save(list = "glmObject", file = "FileName.RData")
}

mainFn <- function(y, x){ 
         subFn(y, x)
}

mainFn(y = rbinom(n = 10, size = 1, prob = 1 / 2), x = 1:10)
```

I saw that the file "FileName.RData" was created in my working directory. It is 6.6 kb in size.

I then use:

```
load("FileName.RData")
```

to load the contents, `glmObject`, to my global environment.