# In R, why does the memory of an object as reported by `object_size()` not match the resulting `.RData` image save of the object?

Tags: r

I have an list object called `my_list` in `R` that is reported to occupy 53 Mb in memory, by calling out:

```
> format(object.size(mylist), units = "auto")
[1] "55 Mb"
```

However, when I save this as an `.RData` image, by calling out:

```
save(list = "mylist", file = "mylist.RData")
```

`mylist.RData` occupies 270 Mb on my hard drive. What is the discrepancy caused by?

Comment: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53423708/access-an-environment-using-reference-id-0x00000000) I had a similar issue

Comment: Someone had the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836747/object-size-reports-smaller-size-than-rdata-file